# concatenation program in C

Tags: c

I have written a program for concatenation two strings, and it is throwing segmentation fault during run time at line s1[i+j] = s2[j], in for loop..... And i am not able to figure out, why it is happening so.... Kindly coreect me, where am i going wrong.

```
char* concatenate(char *s1, char *s2)
{
   int i,j=0;

   for(i=0; s1[i] != '\0'; i++);
   for(j=0; s2[j] != '\0'; j++)
   {
      s1[i+j] = s2[j];
   }
   s1[i+j] = s2[j];

   return s1;
}
```

---

```
   char *s1 = (char *) malloc(15);;
   char *s2 ;

   s1 = "defds";
   s2 = "abcd";

   s1 = concatenate(s1,s2);
//   printf("\n\n%s\n\n",s1);
```

Comment: In order for anyone to answer this question, you need to show the function that _calls_ this function.

Comment: @James is right, and it's a bit silly that several posters jumped in finding all kinds of faults with `concatenate` which (1) are exactly the same problems that `strcat` has, and (2) have nothing to do with the segfault.

Comment: @John: Writing a `strcat` replacement function is useless if your function has the same flaws as `strcat`. By pointing out the flaws, we're simply trying to help the OP avoid those problems and thereby make the world a better place.

Answer (score 8):

```
s1 = "rahul";
```

This line does not copy the string "rahul" into the buffer pointed to by `s1`; it reassigns the pointer `s1` to point to the (not modifiable) string literal "rahul"

You can get the desired functionality by using your `concatenate` function twice:

```
char *s1 = (char *) malloc(15);

s1[0] = '\0'; // make sure the buffer is a null terminated string of length zero
concatenate(s1, "rahul");
concatenate(s1, "bagai");
```

Note that the `concatenate` function is still somewhat unsafe since it blindly copies bytes, much like `strcat` does.  You'll want either to be very sure that the buffer you pass it is large enough, or to modify it to take a buffer length like `strncat` takes.

Answer (score 3):

When you do `s1 = "rahul";` you are overwriting the memory you just allocated. This line doesn't copy "rahul" to the malloc'ed area, it changes `s1` to point to the string constant "rahul" and throws away the pointer to the malloc'ed memory.

Instead, you should use `strcpy` to copy the string to the malloc'ed area:

```
// s1 = "rahul";
strcpy(s1, "rahul");
```

This will fix your call to `concatenate` since `s1` will now point to the correct 15-byte area of memory.

Alternatively, you could eschew the dynamic allocation and allocate+assign the initial string all at once:

```
char s1[15] = "rahul";
```

That will allocate 15 bytes on the stack and copy "rahul" into that space. Note a subtlety here. In this case it is in fact correct to use `=`, whereas it is incorrect when s1 is declared as `char *s1`.

One important debugging lesson you can learn from this is that when your program crashes on a particular line of code that doesn't mean that's where the bug is. Often you make a mistake in one part of your program and that mistake doesn't manifest itself in a crash until later on. This is part of what makes debugging such a delightfully frustrating process!

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to write your own string concatenation, there are already functions in the standard libary to do this task for you!

```
#include <string.h>

char *strcat(char *dest, const char *src);
char *strncat(char *dest, const char *src, size_t n);
```

Comment: I'm curious what that downvote was for - could someone care to explain what's wrong with my solution? Admitedly I described the same flaws `strcat` bears, but at least that rises awareness!

Comment: Perhaps it was because you blindly answered the question without waiting for the OP to clarify the problem and your answer does not actually answer the question?

Comment: Well, the core message is "use strchr" and "don't reinvent the wheel", that point gets across. But I admit I was a bit overly dramatic there. I modified my answer.

Comment: No, the core message is "the bug is in the code calling your function, because your function is fine".

Answer (score 1):

In the second piece of code, you allocate a buffer of size 15 and then assign it to s1. Then you assign "rahul" to s1, which leaks the memory you just allocated, and assigns s1 to a 6-byte piece of memory that you likely cannot write to. Change `s1 = "rahul";` to `strcpy( s1, "rahul" );` and you might have better luck.

I agree with the other answers though, the concatenate function is dangerous.